# M/M/1 vs G/G/1 vs G/M/1

Tags: queueing-theory

I am using queuing theory to model a router.
I have a model that assumes Poisson traffic and I need to modify it as my actual traffic is not Poisson

I want to ask what's the main difference between Poisson arrivals and general arrivals  in terms of results ?

ie what are the formulas that don't hold if we don't have Poisson assumption ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general inter-arrival times instead of Possion, the formulas are expressed in terms of a general cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ so to use them you need to have a distribution in mind.

Look at Introduction to Probability Models Eleventh Edition by Sheldon M. Ross
for reference.

Comment: I m not very familiar with queuing theory . In my specific case , I need to know if the formula for utilization still hold  ( arrival rate / service rate )  All I can think about is to calculate again the arriva rate according to distribution but I cannot see how the general formula arrival rate / service rate wont hold

Comment: I'm fairly certain that those equations change if you don't assume an exponential distribution, yes.